# Report based on time difference calculation

Tags: reporting

I am building a report which will show contracts which were Closed within 5 days of being initiated (Open Date). Is there a way to build a filter in reports based on the simple formula : (Closed Date - Open Date) < 5 ? Or is it necessary for me to build a separate formula field which calculates that date difference - and then build a report filter based on that field's value ?

Comment: You will need to create a formula field for this purpose...

Comment: That's what I figured. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something. Thanks Nathan.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating Matrix,Summary Reports, you get an option to Add Formula but that is mostly related to Summary Fields. It will not be what you are looking here. 

The best option will be to have your own formula field, it will give you more flexibility in terms of filtering results.

Rgds,
Dave